PNG look all messed up compared to the rendered view

When I'm in blender it looks fine but when I try to render it the model gets jumbled up.

Please take screenshots instead of taking pictures of your (curved!) monitor. Makes it much harder to figure out what's going on. The only thing I can see is you are rendering with a transparent background. If the background is a reference image, it will not be rendered. Or are you talking about the object looking completely different? Well, what about giving us some information...? Are there animation on the object, the camera or something like that? Are there objects hidden in the viewport but not in render? Would it be too much to ask if you could show the whole screen (with Outliner)?

you definitely have a hidden object in a viewport that is visible in the render
